# Writing a package that uses many function from tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, devtools, roxygen2

I am trying to organize my code in a package instead of using `source`. Do I need to include,  e.g `@import dplyr` in all my roxygen2 tags? I have these packages in my DESCRIPTION file:

```
Imports: 
    dplyr,
    ggplot2,
    forcats,
    purrr,
    tibble,
    colorspace,
    extrafont,
    tidyr,
    forcats,
    magrittr
```

Do I need to specify the external functions in my package 2 times? I.e. once in the DESCRIPTION file and once in the import tag?
Also: Do I need to use `::` even though I have included `@import` min the roxygen headers?

Comment: You only need to import a package namespace once. However, it is good practice to add all imports a function needs in its @import directive. It's also good practice to import specific functions instead of the whole namespace. You don't need :: if you imported the function (except if you have name collisions because different imported packages define functions with the same name like stats::filter and dplyr::filter).

Comment: @ Roland. Thanks for answer. I am still confused because the DESCRIPTION file has an Import and in the file with the function there is also @import. So where should I do it once?

Comment: The DESCRIPTION file lists the packages that you are doing imports from.  It's used so that R knows what dependencies to install.  The NAMESPACE file (which roxygen2 creates based on the @import directives) lists the actual functions imported.  It is used to install those functions in the namespace of your package so that they can be accessed without the :: operator.

Comment: @ user 2554330: Okay thanks, so if I e.g. write ``@import dplyr`` all the functions in dplyr will be available in my  NAMESPACE? How important is it to specify which function I am going to use in the function e.g. ``@import dplyr mutate``? Also lets say I use  ``@import dplyr mutate`` in one function, to I need to write this again in another function that uses ``mutate`` from ``dplyr`?

Comment: Importing whole namespaces instead of specific functions increases the risk of name collisions. All functions in your package have access to your package's namespace and thus to all functions imported into that namespace.

Comment: @ Roland: okay great, so e.g I use importFrom dplyr mutate in one of my functions and the next function that uses mutate does not include a importFrom dplyr mutate. Right?

Comment: It doesn't need to but it would still be good practice ...